# Removing the split between merged polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, merge, vertices

I merged two polygons within one shapefile and then aligned all the vertices so that they were adjacent, but how do I remove the former edges that bisect the polygon so that the geometry is continuous?

Sometimes unmerging then re-aligning the vertices and remerging the polygons in the advanced digitizing toolbar fixes this. I'm not sure why it doesn't always work

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect you want to `union` the polygon parts rather than `merge` them - if there is a boundary between them then you haven't joined them correctly

Comment: They need to be coincident along their boundary, i.e. each vertice in one poly is matched by a vertice in the other.  So prior to merger you could run the snap tool or the v.clean tool with a tolerance large enough to fill the gaps but not so large as to change shapes unacceptably.